# Network tools that simulate slow network connection

Tags: networking, performance, simulate

I would like to visually evaluate web pages response time for several Internet connections types (DSL, Cable, T1, dial-up etc.) while my browser and web server are on the same LAN or even on the same machine. Are there any simple network tools or browser plug-ins that slow down network bandwidth to simulate different real-world connection scenarios.

I appreciate any input on that.

Comment: Just a note, you might cross-post this on serverfault.com.

Comment: OSX Mountain Lion users can use Network Link Conditioner - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699805/where-is-network-link-conditioner-prefpane-in-osx-mountain-lion-and-xcode-4-4.

Comment: https://github.com/shopify/toxiproxy

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58513277/2178980

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try [Traffic Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html)
you can easily limit speed of IE or other browser with this App and its also freeware

Comment: kaspersky reports the download from that site as containing a trojan downloader program.

Comment: Symantec Enpdpoint Protection didn't find any problems with the file.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows 7.

Comment: http://joemiller.me/2010/08/31/simulate-network-latency-packet-loss-and-bandwidth-on-mac-osx/

Comment: I could not get that to work. Does it support traffic to localhost or 127.0.0.1 address?

Comment: @Anderson, Probably not. As far as I recall, Windows doesn't have a internal network stack for local connections like *nix usually does.

Comment: I use Clumsy (http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html) myself.

Answer (score 284):

On Linux, see [netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem): the kernel already contains support for traffic shaping, and can simulate high latency, low bandwidth, packet losses, and all sort of other adverse conditions, even on a loopback device (so you don't need a real, physical network to test across).

Comment: +1 to this.  Awesome.  With a single command I can make "localhost" behave like a public internet service on coffee shop wifi:

`sudo tc qdisc add dev lo root netem delay 500ms`

Comment: Sweet! The docs are here: http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Comment: Super cool. Just want to add how to remove the emulation again.

To add: `sudo tc qdisc add dev lo root netem delay 100ms`
To remove: `sudo tc qdisc del dev lo root netem delay 100ms`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832505/simulating-a-bad-internet-connection/15824081#15824081

Comment: You can completely reset all tc rules for loopback with the single command `sudo tc qdisc del dev lo root` - change `lo` to `eth0` if you're using a wired connection etc

Comment: Recent versions of netem support limiting the bandwidth too using the rate option: `tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1:0 netem delay 10ms rate 1mbit limit 1000`. Note that for some devices, such as the loopback device, you also need to set it to have a non-zero queue length for the rate option to work: `ifconfig lo txqueuelen 1000`. See http://serverfault.com/a/394949/76090

Comment: Also for Linux is the command-line tool wondershaper: ```sudo apt install wondershaper; sudo wondershaper eth0 128 64``` will throttle the eth0 interface to 128  kilobits down, 64 up.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead. Does anyone know where the documentation moved to?

Answer (score 81):

I am resurrecting this thread because I had the same need recently.
Amazingly, I discovered that Fiddler can be used to do that by customizing the rules and adding this line `oSession["response-trickle-delay"] = "150";` in the section `OnBeforeResponse`.

Fiddler is really amazing.

Comment: In recent versions of Fiddler, you only need to enable `Simulate Modem Speeds` under Rules -> Performance.

Comment: +1 Fiddler is an exceptional tool, perhaps overkill for just this but definitely worth having around.  You can easily get Fiddler to only fiddle with one program by using the process filter, no setting up of proxies in your program needed!

Comment: I was already a lover of Fiddler but now I just can't live without it. I didn't know that the tool I need lives with me every day :)

Comment: Note that this is a windows-only solution, unless you are willing to fiddle with hacks and workarounds.

Answer (score 21):

Try Microsoft's NEWT, it worked perfect for me. It supplies customized latency, packet drop techniques and more :)

http://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/

**Update 1:**

Here is a good video tutorial for NEWT -
[Network Emulator For Windows Toolkit Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5o_GnYOloA) (Credits to Jimmery)

Comment: Does this work like fiddler (ie. is it invisible to the client and server apps?)

Comment: Yes, I think it's working in the driver level.

Comment: I tried it, but I couldn't figure it out - is there a help file anywhere?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, but you'll have to know some basic network concepts before using this tool.

Comment: I know basic networking concepts - but couldn't get it to do anything.

Comment: Use the trace button (looks like a yellow foot) to see if your filters are relevant to any network packets. Try simple stuff, like dropping every packet for port 80 (HTTP).

Comment: Same here; I'm a developer, I've written TCP level C++ code before -- have configured QoS (and many other things) in detail for routers -- I have a network intensive app running (downloading/uploading 2 - 4 Mb/s right now) -- Tried the tracing, and also "Action->Toggle Tracing", but nothing happens.  Also don't see any relevant way to setup bandwidth throttling... so that's annoying.

Comment: Ive not got the network knowledge of you guys, but I got NEWT to work after watching this youtube vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5o_GnYOloA - I hope this helps

Comment: Didn't work on windows8.1

Comment: @RanP, Make sure you press 'F5' to start the throttling action. You have to start it explicitly.

Answer (score 18):

My work uses this tool, and it seems quite good:
http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/

Best of luck.

Comment: +1 Java-based, so it works great on OSX (haven't tried it on Windows or Linux yet) - easy to install & run, works transparently, and doesn't leave a mess afterwards!

Comment: yep, excellent tool, web based jnlp (no install needed, just launch it) it creates a proxy on localhost, port is configurable, speed can be changed dynamically +32 ;)

Comment: I've used **sloppy** before and I love it, but sadly it does not support `https`: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sloppy-discuss/tOyCx7igfkw

Comment: doesn't simulate the packet loss of crappy networks though.

Answer (score 14):

I've successfully used [TMnetSim](http://www.tmurgent.com/appv/index.php/resources/tools) (bottom of the page, under “Other Tools” - the link says something like “ZIP: TMnetSim Network Simulator version 2.4 32-bit (600KB)”

It's not just for websites - you can slow connections to any TCP port. I was using it to simulate a slow SQL Server (port 1433).

Comment: What OS were you using?  I couldn't get it to work at all under 32-bit Windows 7...

Comment: @GuyBehindtheGuy: did you ever have any luck? I have the same need and OS...

Comment: I ended up using DummyNet.  There's a Windows version here: http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/

Comment: +1 This one did _exactly_ what I needed with the minimal amount of fuzz. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Current version is working on 64-bit Windows 8.1 just fine.

Comment: Can TMnetSim be used to simulate a slow SQL Server connection when the server is running on the local machine?  If so, what are the settings?

Answer (score 6):

[DummyNet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/)

Try this FreeBSD based VMWare image. It also has an excellent how-to, purely free and stands up in 20 minutes.

Update: DummyNet also supports Linux, OSX and Windows by now

Comment: Thanks for the tip on this.  Turns out there's now a native Windows version available, which I used successfully.

Comment: I went this way. But configuration took me ~4 hours. I should have known to replace "192.168.0." to "192.168.196." (the subnet) through *all* the rc.conf and rc.firewall.

Answer (score 6):

I love [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

The free version works fine for me.

Throttling, rerwiting, breakpoints are all awesome features.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine for 30 days... :-/

Comment: For me it works fine also after the 30 days, you just have to wait a little longer and it reboots after 30 minutes. But you can always get the license.

Comment: Version 3.7?  The website seems to imply that after 30 days you have to purchase it to continue using it.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. In the first 30 days you can use it without delays. After that there are small delays and it reboots after 30 minutes.

Comment: From their Website: `After 30 days if you decide to continue using Charles you must purchase a license`

Comment: for others benefit: Charles 3 and 4 gave me very unstable results when throttling. Pretty much every throttle setting didn't work as expected except for utilization %.

Answer (score 6):

For Linux or OSX, you can use `ipfw`.

From Quora (http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-tool-to-simulate-a-slow-internet-connection-on-a-Mac)

Essentially using a firewall to throttle all network data:

> Define a rule that uses a pipe to reroute all traffic from any source
>   address to any destination address, execute the following command (as
>   root, or using sudo):
>
> `$ ipfw add pipe 1 all from any to any`
>
> To configure this rule to limit bandwidth to 300Kbit/s and impose
>   200ms of latency each way:
>
> `$ ipfw pipe 1 config bw 300Kbit/s delay 200ms`
>
> To remove all rules and recover your original network connection:
>
> `$ ipfw flush`

Answer (score 4):

If you use Apache, you can use mod_bandwith.

See [here](http://www.cohprog.com/mod_bandwidth_config) for configuration parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Mac OS X has now an integrated tool able to simulate slow and bad networks : http://9to5mac.com/2011/08/10/new-in-os-x-lion-network-link-conditioner-utility-lets-you-simulate-internet-and-bandwidth-conditions/

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like a hardware solution, Netgear has a series of cheap ($50 or so) switches that do bandwidth limiting. Netgear Prosafe GS105E and similar switches are worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) which is an open source Wide Area Network emulator. You can download the image (ISO, Knoppix live CD) or VMWare virtual appliances.

Answer (score 2):

A simple mac GUI program is

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28072/entonnoir/ which can limit the speed

Answer (score 1):

You can use dummynet ofcourse, There is extension of dummynet called [KauNet](http://www.kau.se/en/kaunet/download). which can provide even more precise control of network conditions. It can drop/delay/re-order specific packets (that way you can perform more in-depth analysis of dropping key packets like TCP handshake to see how your web pages digest it). It also works in time domain. Usually most the emulators are tuned to work in data domain. In time domain you can specify from what time to what time you can alter the network conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to simulate network connection quality when developing for Windows Phone, you might give a try to a Visual Studio built-in tool called Simulation Dashboard (more details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206952(v=vs.105).aspx):

> You can use the Simulation Dashboard in Visual Studio to test your app
>   for these connection problems, and to help prevent users from
>   encountering scenarios like the following:
>
> - High-resolution music or videos stutter or freeze while streaming, or take a long time to download over a low-bandwidth connection.
> - Calls to a web service fail with a timeout.
> - The app crashes when no network is available.
> - Data transfer does not resume when the network connection is lost and then restored.
> - The user’s battery is drained by a streaming app that uses the network inefficiently.
> - Mapping the user’s route is interrupted in a navigation app.
>
> ...
>
> In Visual Studio, on the **Tools** menu, open **Simulation Dashboard**. Find
>   the network simulation section of the dashboard and check the **Enable
>   Network Simulation check box**.