# Implementing file upload progress with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi Im attempting to implement upload progress with Zend however I havent found any detailed tutorials. A pointer would be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at the manual page of Zend_File? http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.file.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction.uploadprogress

Answer (score 12):

I don't remember having ever seen a fully-detailled tutorial explaining how to get a progress bar for uploads with Zend Framework ; but here are a few pointers, that should guide you a bit, provided you already know so stuff about PHP, file uploads, and Zend Framework...

First of all, you'll need one of those two PHP extension installed :

- either [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/apc)
- or [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress)

Which mean you'll be able to get that kind of progress bar only if you are admin of your server *(those kind of extensions are generally not installed by default -- and not on shared hosting)*

Then, you have to use some special "hidden" fields in your upload form ; about that, you can take a look at the [configuration options of APC](http://fr3.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.rfc1867) ; especially those related to RFC 1867.

If you are using Zend Framework, I suppose you are already using some [`Zend_Form_Element_File`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file) in your form. It should already do what is necessary about those fields -- you'd better check that, to be sure, btw.

Now that you form is OK, you can finally take a look at [`Zend_ProgressBar`](http://Zend_ProgressBar), and at the documentation chapter that describes [Progress for file uploads](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.file.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction.uploadprogress)

Your code will probably look a bit like this *(quoting the doc)* :

```
$adapter = new Zend_ProgressBar_Adapter_Console();
$upload  = Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http::getProgress($adapter);

$upload = null;
while (!$upload['done']) {
    $upload = Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http:getProgress($upload);
}
```

And, to fetch that information regularly, you'll have to do some polling from the web page, using some kind of Ajax requests.

About the uploadprogress extension, you can take a look at these articles :

- [Upload Progress Meter - Common issues and some answers](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2009/03/31/upload-progress-meter-common-issues-and-some-answers.html) -- it might give you a few pointers.
- [AJAX File upload Progress](http://blog.joshuaeichorn.com/archives/2005/05/01/ajax-file-upload-progress/) and [PHP AJAX File Upload Progress Meter Updates](http://blog.joshuaeichorn.com/archives/2006/03/14/php-ajax-file-upload-progress-meter-updates/)
- [Upload Progress Meter extension for PHP 5.2](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2006/09/10/upload-progress-meter-extension-for-php-5-2.html)

Those posts are not specifically targetting Zend Framework, but might give you an idea of what is going on ;-)

BTW, you'll probably want to test all that on your local machine, which is easier to develop... And that will mean that file upload will really be **fast** ; which is not quite good to test any kind of progress upload indicator...

About that, you might be interesting in "slowing down" your local network interface ; those might help :

- [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)
- [Firefox plugin to simulate slow internet connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection)

Hope this helps at least a bit **;-)**

And, while you're at it : why don't you write down your findings into some kind of nice and detailled tutorial ? That might be useful to some people **;-)**