# Simulating Slow Internet Connection

Tags: performance, networking

I know this is kind of an odd question. Since I usually develop applications based on the "assumption" that all users have a slow internet connection. But, does anybody think that there is a way to programmatically simulate a slow internet connection, so I can "see" how an application performs under various "connection speeds"?

I'm not worried about which language is used. And I'm not looking for code samples or anything, just interested in the logic behind it.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If you're running windows, [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great tool.  It has a setting to simulate modem speed, and for someone who wants more control has a [plugin to add latency to each request](http://fiddlerdelayext.codeplex.com/).

I prefer using a tool like this to putting latency code in my application as it is a much more realistic simulation, as well as not making me design or code the actual bits.  The best code is code I don't have to write.

*ADDED*: This article at Pavel Donchev's blog on Software Technologies shows how to create custom simulated speeds: [Limiting your Internet connection speed with Fiddler](http://donchevp.blogspot.com.es/2009/11/limiting-your-internet-connection-speed.html).

Comment: Hi I wrote a little guide on simulating a slow internet connection that might come in useful: http://www.developertipoftheday.com/2010/12/simulate-slow-internet-connection-in.html - full disclosure - this is my own blog, but just in case it helps as I'm all for spreading the good word of fiddler :-)

Comment: The trouble with this fiddler approach is that the latency simulation is not accurate, it operates at the wrong protocol level so you do not get to properly simulate slow start.

Comment: @SamSaffron, Sorry to dig up an old post like this, but, do you know any other tools which help in simulation of slow starts?

Comment: @AnishRam best bet is to use dummynet/ipfw that ships with bsd and family, freebsd, osx etc http://barkingiguana.com/2009/12/04/simulating-slow-or-laggy-network-connections-in-os-x/

Comment: @AnishRam Also see netem http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem can simulate a bunch of conditions using iproute2.

Comment: In Fiddler, `Rules > Performance> Simulate modem speeds`.  This "simulates typical 56k modem conditions".  If you're an expert, you can also go to `Rules > Customize Rules`.

Comment: Can we get an updated answer for this? This plugin is discontinued and doesn't seem to work.

Comment: seems that it's pay now?

Answer (score 169):

Starting with **Chrome 38** you can do this without any plugins. Just click inspect element (or <kbd>F12</kbd> hotkey), then click on "toggle device mod"[image] and you will see something like this:

[image]

Among many other features it allows you to simulate specific internet connection (3G, GPRS)

It seems to only work if you have the devtools side bar open.

**P.S.2** now you do not need to toggle anything. Throttling panel is available right from the network panel. [image]

Note that while clicking on the **No throttling** you can create your custom throttling options.

[image]

Comment: Now Chrome Dev Tools throttling limits both download and upload speed. But it only limit it for current page in Chrome, so you can't use it to test your page in other browsers. In order to do that you need to use other tools like Fiddler.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that currently WebSockets are not throttled this way: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423246

Comment: Upload throttling hasn't worked in quite a few versions of Chrome including the latest (70.0). There's a [bug report on the tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414319).

Comment: In my experience, the biggest cause of web slowness is cable ISPs' flaky DNS being unable to resolve ad servers or CDNs. Sometimes the entire page remains blank until the attempt to resolve them succeeds or times out. Can Chrome simulate this?

Answer (score 54):

[Google recommends](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=de#network-throttling):

- [Network Link Conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) on OSX
- [Clumsy](http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html) on Windows
- [Dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) on Linux

Comment: Network Link Conditioner is maintained by Apple (so it's stable and reliable), BUT it only applies to Xcode's simulator.

Comment: @BenWheeler Tried it recently it is surely been applied system wide, even localhost

Comment: I can confirm that Network Link Conditioner is indeed applied to the entire network stack.

Answer (score 19):

On Linux machines u can use `wondershaper`

```
apt-get install wondershaper

$ sudo wondershaper {interface} {down} {up}
```

the {down} and {up} are bandwidth in kpbs

So for example if you want to limit the bandwidth of interface eth1 to 256kbps uplink and 128kbps downlink,

```
$ sudo wondershaper eth1 256 128
```

To clear the limit,

```
$ sudo wondershaper clear eth1
```

Answer (score 13):

I was using http://www.netlimiter.com/ and it works very well. Not only limit speed for single processes but also shows actual transfer rates.

Comment: Most of the other tools provide bandwidth control via artificial latency which doesn't seem to be case with netlimiter which is a good thing. However, in the end it's a commercial tool(with a trial version) and only available under Windows.

Answer (score 6):

There are TCP proxies out there, like iprelay and Sloppy, that do bandwidth shaping to simulate slow connections. You can also do bandwidth shaping and simulate packet loss using IP filtering tools like ipfw and iptables.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look into iprelay and Sloppy joe.

Comment: Thanks, ipfw works great. Here's a quick guide I saw that was helpful: http://barkingiguana.com/2009/12/04/simulating-slow-or-laggy-network-connections-in-os-x/

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/), it can simulates queue and bandwidth limitations, delays, packet losses, and multipath effects

Answer (score 4):

Use a web debugging proxy with throttling features, like Charles or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

You'll find them useful web development in general. The major difference is that Charles is shareware, whereas Fiddler is free.

Comment: You run it as a proxy. The browser automatically connects to it, and it forwards requests to your web app.

Comment: For Fiddler, it has both modes to work inside/outside of browser.

Answer (score 4):

Also, for simulating a slow connection on some *nixes, you can try using [ipfw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipfirewall). More information is provided by Ben Newman's answer on this Quora [question](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-tool-to-simulate-a-slow-internet-connection-on-a-Mac)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [NetEm (Network Emulation)](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) as a **proxy server to emulate many network characteristics** (speed, delay, packet loss, etc.). It controls the networking using [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) package and it's enabled in the kernel of most Linux distributions.

It is controlled by the `tc` command-line application (from the *iproute2* package), but there are also some web interface GUIs for NetEm, for example [PHPnetemGUI2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpnetemgui2/).

The advantage is that, as I wrote, it can emulate not only different *network speeds* but also, for example, the *packet loss*, *duplication and/or corruption*, *random or defined delay*, etc., so apart from the slow connections, you can also emulate various poorly performing networks and transmission errors.

For your application it's absolutely transparent, you can configure the operating system to use the NetEm as a proxy server, so all connections from that machine will be routed through it. Or you can configure only a specific application to use that proxy.

I have been using it to test the performance of an Android app on various emulated poor-performance networks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like [TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html#slow). It can fake a slow connection.

Basically, you request it the exact same thing and it just forwards the exact same request to the real server, and then delays the response with only the set amount of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, the following list of papers might be useful:

- [A Comparative Study of Network Link Emulators (2009)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.434.4348&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [KauNet: A Versatile and Flexible Emulation System (2009)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/41205346_KauNet_A_Versatile_and_Flexible_Emulation_System)
- [Dummynet Revisited (2010)](http://ccr.sigcomm.org/online/files/p13-15v40n2e-carboneA.pdf)
- [Measuring Accuracy and Performance of Network Emulators (2015)](https://www.rationali.st/blog/files/20151126-jittertrap/lubke2014measuring0.pdf)

Personally, whilst [Dummynet](https://github.com/luigirizzo/dummynet) is good, I find [NetEm](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) to be the most versatile for my use-cases; I'm usually interested in the effect of delays, rather than bandwidth (i.e. WiFi connection issues), and it's super-easy to emulate random packet loss/corruption, etc. It's also very accessible, and free (unlike the hardware-based [Linktropy](https://www.apposite-tech.com/products/linktropy/)).

On a side-note, for Windows, [Clumsy](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/index.html) is awesome. I would also like to add that (regarding websites) browser throttling is not an accurate method for emulating real-life network issues (I think "TKK" commented on a few of the reasons why above).

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

One common case of shaping a single TCP connection can actually be assembled from dual pairs of `socat` and `cpipe` in UNIX fashion like this:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:5555,reuseaddr,reuseport,fork SYSTEM:'cpipe -ngr -b 1 -s 10 | socat - "TCP:localhost:5000" | cpipe -ngr -b 1 -s 300'`

This simulates a connection with bandwidth of approximately 300kB/s *from* your service at `:5000` and *to* at approximately 10kB/s and listens on `:5555` for incoming connections. **Caveat**: Note that this *per-connection*, so each individual TCP connection gets this amount.

Explanation: 
The outer (left) `socat` listens with the given options on `:5555` as a forking server. The first `cpipe` command in the `SYSTEM:...` option then throttles data that went *into* socket :5555 (and comes out of the first, outer `socat`) to at most 10kByte/s. That data is then forwarding using another `socat` which connects to `localhost:5000` (where the service you want to slow down should be listening). Data *from* `localhost:5000` is then put into the right `cpipe` command, which (with the given values) throttles it to about 300kB/s.

The option `-ngr` to `cpipe` is important. It causes cpipe to read non-greedily from its input file-descriptor. Otherwise, you might get stuck with data in the buffers not being forwarded and waiting for a reply.

Using the more common `buffer` tool instead of `cpipe` is likely possible as well.

(Credits: This is based on the "double-tee" recipe by Christophe Loor from the `socat` documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Mac OSX since 10.10 has an app called [Murus Firewall](http://www.murusfirewall.com/), which acts as a GUI to pf, the replacement for ipfw.

It works very well for system-wide or domain-specific throttling. I was just able to use it to slide my download speed between 300Kbps and 30Mbps to test how a streaming video player adjusts.

Answer (score 1):

Updating this (9 years after it was asked) as the answer I was looking for wasn't mentioned:

Firefox also has presets for throttling connection speeds. Find them in the **Network Monitor** tab of the developer tools. Default is 'No throttling'.

Slowest is **GPRS** (*Download speed: 50 Kbps, Upload speed: 20 Kbps, Minimum latency (ms): 500*), ranging through 'good' and 'regular' 2G, 3G and 4G to DSL and **WiFi** (*Download speed: 30Mbps, Upload speed: 15Mbps, Minimum latency (ms): 2*).

More in the [Dev Tools docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Throttling).

Answer (score 0):

There is also another tool called WIPFW  - http://wipfw.sourceforge.net/

It's a bit old school, but you can use it to simulate a slower connection. It's Windows based, and the tool allows the administrator to monitor how much traffic the router is getting from a certain machine, or how much WWW traffic it is forwarding, for example.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple and practical way to do it, without any application or code. Just connect to the internet using a mobile hotspot. Keep moving the hotspot (phone) away from the connected device to simulate slower networks.

Comment: this method is difficult to measure and not applicable to remote servers

Comment: You should understand the use of the word "simulating" in the question before answering.
OP does not want to slow down/or destabilize his connection but to simulate a slow connection.