# slowly internet simulation on localhost with YSlow

Tags: localhost, yslow

I want create slowly internet simulation on my local server (I use xammp). For this I install 
YSlow for google chrome, but i not found in this program, how to make slowly internet speed simulation, can anyone help me? where is this settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YSlow is a tool for measuring a web page against a set of performance rules. In spite of the word "slow" in the name, it's not a tool you could use to simulate a slow network connection.

Here are some Q&A that cover different options for simulating a slow network connection:

- [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)
- [Simulating Slow Internet Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536249/simulating-slow-internet-connection)
- https://superuser.com/questions/297103/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection