# Is there a way to limit speed and response time in Node (Express)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to see how my website reacts to a slow connection.

Is there a way I can limit express to responding with slow speeds or delays? I know I can implement `setTimeout` calls on paths, but what about static assets?

Comment: You can [simulate various connection speeds (and more)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/network-conditions?hl=en) through your browser

Comment: Totally did not know that.

Comment: For completeness sake, if there is a node way of doing this please answer and I'll up vote.

Comment: You can use [crapify](https://github.com/bcoe/crapify) for node

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, modern browsers support network speed simulation (and much more). Doing any programatic latency faking within your app is not a good approach because network simulation is difficult, it's hard to do it reliably and you could end up polluting your code a lot.

You should use a browser to do this:

- [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/network-conditions?hl=en) (best support)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Tips_and_Tricks#Simulating_Slow(er)_Internet_Connections)
- Edge (not yet supported but it [has been suggested](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9772116-f12-emulation-of-slow-network-connections))

There are also many other tools and resources you can use:

- [crapify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crapify) (NodeJS)
- [How to simulate slow connection on a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac)
- [Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3536274/3928341)
- [and many more...](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20simulate%20slow%20connection%20o&oq=How%20to%20simulate%20slow%20connection%20o&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60.270j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=How%20to%20simulate%20slow%20connection%20on)