# How to make slower my web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to see how my web page works when it's loading slowly. Does anyone know how to make slower a web page ?
I'm using HTML, CSS, Javascript and jQuery. Is this an unnecessary work ?

Comment: Chrome has some tools to simulate this. I think it is in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Chrome dev tools (command+option+J on mac, or control+option+j on windows I think), and select the [network throttling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/network-conditions) option.

[image]

Comment: ctrl+shift+i on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Many modern Browsers are shipped with such functionality. For example Firefox can do it like [this](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/11/07/simulate-slow-connections-with-the-network-throttling-tool/). 
There exists a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536249/simulating-slow-internet-connection#26313279) on SO.

Comment: That similar question looks like a duplicate to me. I've flagged for closure.