# How can I limit the load speed of an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

A slightly unusual problem. I need to limit the speed that an html page downloads at, and I need the code that achieves this to fit within the < head > section. Is this possible?

Tried PHP's sleep function but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Did you tried with ```lazy-load```?

Comment: please explain in greater detail what you are trying to achieve. For example, you can hide page with javascript for required time. Provide more details.

Comment: Do you mean from initial request from the browser or from first byte received from the response? There is a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure. The end result I'd like is that the page loads slowly for the user, as if their connection speed is poor.

Comment: There are some good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536249/simulating-slow-internet-connection

Comment: Please tell us why you would like to achieve that. If it is to simulate slow network it is not possible (without extensions), but other reasons might be doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout()` as described on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

First, you would change the `display` property of the body to `none`.

```
<body style="display:none">
```

Then you would create a function that gets the `body` element and changes the `display` property to `block`.

```
function myFunction() {
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.style.display = "block";
}
```

Followed by the use of `setTimeout()`. In the example below, I have set the timeout to 3 seconds. The function will execute after 3 seconds.

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
```

```js
function myFunction() {
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.style.display = "block";
}
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="display:none">
<h1>Time out</h1>
</body>
</html>
```