# firefox plugin to test web application

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

is there any firefox plugin to emulate slow internet connection or emulate unstable internet connection to test web app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-plugin-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection-or-limit-bandwidth

Comment: @cometta, the link is broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extensions, network tools can be used to simulate different connection behaviours - see e.g. [*"Network tools that simulate slow network connection"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection) or [*"Bandwidth throttling software"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235252/bandwidth-throttling-software).

Unless for some reasons the APIs exposed by FireFox give extensions control over its networking features, this wouldn't even be doable without external applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any but if you have a phone with a data plan, you could use it as "internet provider" on you PC in order to simulate the slow connection ([Tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering))