# How can i simulate a slow network connection

Tags: networking, performance, simulate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)

I have a Bet Server which sends bet data to a game terminal
I would like to simulate a slow network connection.  i want the network to be really busy, heavily loaded so i can see how the bet server performs and if it times out when there is a heavy load on the network.

Are there any tools i can use to do this?

Thanks for any help.
Regards, Riaz

Comment: Which environment? Which programming language? What type of client?

Comment: How about running multiple game terminal instance mocks and generating a lot of network data?

Comment: Hook another computer to the network and download a bunch of junk from bittorrent. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of plugins you can try.
[Firefox Throttle is one of them](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5917)

Edit: this assuming you're developing a browser-based thingy.

Comment: The Bet Server is an application sending data on Port 2222
It's not a web app.
Our Customer has a busy network and the bet server is dropping packets, timing out.
Our Office LAN is not busy so we do not see this issue.

I would like a tool which can slow our network down, make the network busy so i can see if the Bet Server drops packets, times out
I am testing this, not a developer ;)

Comment: Well,  I'd go with what lewiguez said in the other post then; try ipfw.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of things that happen during high network congestion; lost packets, retransmissions, filled buffers/queues. The best way is to create the test network traffic and traffic loads for each type of situation. They **must** be reproducible.

You should use a traffic generator like IXIA's http://www.ixiacom.com/  traffic generator for this.   This device allows you to create test cases with different loads on the network, both pointing at your application and just overall network congestion.  You can even simulate network attacks on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection). It has a lot of good answers. If you're Mac or Linux, you can use ipfw as well. Just google ipfw or `man ipfw` for the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) which is an open source Wide Area Network emulator. You can download the image (ISO, Knoppix live CD) or VMWare virtual appliances.

Answer (score -1):

[SLOPPY](http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/)