# PHP configuration: max_execution_time and max_input_time

Tags: php

Can I set the following PHP configuration parameters as follows:

max_execution_time = 360
max_input_time 360

Is that safe and efficient ?

I actually need my user to upload large videos with the php-based Content Management System.

So, each video upload takes some minutes. Do I need to change both and the values are good ?

thanks

Comment: in my opinion, this would depend largely on the average ISP speed of your users. So unless you have a finite definition of your users, we cannot say what are the most efficient values.

Comment: If you're setting execution time > 300, you might also need to check your webserver configuration for a timeout setting as well... but any file that takes so long to upload is tking too long

Comment: so what is your suggested value for let's say.. videos of 24MB to upload with PHP-based CMS ?

Comment: @Patrick - use something like uploadify if your users are uploading such large volumes of data, or get higher bandwidth

Comment: @Mark how would uploadify improve the situation? It's subject to the same limitations on the server's end, isn't it?

Comment: @Pekka - I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that it supports restarting an upload from the point where it failed... so even if the connection fails/times out, it'll start again from the point of failure on a retry (and this retry can be automated, making it transparent to the user, within the jQuery logic)

Comment: @Mark sure, but that is no good if it's hitting the same limit all the time... Don't get me wrong, I *love* Uploadify, I just don't think it will help if you get a timeout due to an oversized file

Comment: @Mark ah, now I understand what you mean! No, as far as I know, uploadify does not have "resume" functionality. It's just a plain file upload through other means

Comment: @Pekka - My bad, although it looks like some other uploaders such as plupload (http://www.plupload.com/) do support this "chunking" feature

Comment: @Mark interesting! Will have to look into that. That would be brilliant for uploads from shaky connections

Comment: @both-of-you: I'm using Drupal upload plugins and I would like to just use Drupal for video uploading. I know that with FTP would be better, but I want to keep it simple for any customer. So again, what's your suggested value for let's say a video of 24MB ? What are the drawbacks of setting high values ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my understanding, you have to change neither.

If you just store the video files using `move_uploaded_file`, you will not need to increase your `max_execution_time` as upload time does not count towards execution time.

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) says the following about `max_input_time` (emphasis mine):

> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to **parse** input data, like POST, GET and file uploads.

I have not tested this, but to me this sounds like it *doesn't* include the actual time the client spends uploading the file, just the time it takes to copy it to the temporary directory. I can't vouch for this though, and I can't find any info on it. The default of 60 seconds should be ample time to parse many hundreds of megabytes of files.

I'd recommend to find out the perfect value using real-life tests. If your connection is too fast, use a tool to slow it down. See this SO question for suggestions:

[Network tools that simulate slow network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)

Comment: ok, so just to summarize: I only need to change post_max_size and upload_max_filesize ? thanks

Comment: @Patrick, That's for byte limit. But if your webserver is slow, you may need to increase time limit ([`max_input_time`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11387113/632951)) to parse those bytes that you receive.  If you would like to operate on the bytes you've received, you would also need to increase the time limit for execution on the PHP side (`max_execution_time`) after the web server has finished its task. Lastly, control memory limits with `memory_limit` and GC with `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

Comment: Outstanding Solution

Answer (score 4):

In my case, `max_input_time` *does* affect my `move_uploaded_file` function. I failed to upload a 3GB file with default setting (`max_input_time=60`) but it succeeded with a larger value (`max_input_time=300`).

My PHP version is *7.2.19* on *LAMP* enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

By default `max_input_time` is equal to -1, which, [according to the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time), means that `max_execution_time` is used instead.

You can therefore leave max_input_time on the default setting of `-1`, and just change `max_execution_time` as needed.

Answer (score -2):

By default my server has max_input_time as -1.  I'm assuming that means infinite.

Comment: this is not advisable, it could lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: 0 means infinite. -1 means equal to max_execution_time.

Comment: According to my XAMPP php.ini settings, max_input_time = -1 means unlimited and it is default value.

Comment: @infomasud That's not correct. [See the documentation.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)