# When using a flash uploader, do I have to change any php.ini settings?

Tags: php, linux

I need to upload files that are up to 200 MB. I was told flash uploader is the way to go such as uploadify or swfupload. Do I have to change any php.ini settings for the uploader to work with large files such as 200MB? Any preventative measures that can be taken to make sure DDoS attack isn't something I'd encounter or make sure people are uploading trully 200 MB max filesize ? Using Cent OS 6, php 5.3

Comment: Just a note: Flash is deprecated on mobile devices now...so your uploader won't work on iphone for one and flash has been taken off of Android Market place last I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure how flash uploaders work since I have always tried to ingore them for the reason in my comment:

> Just a note: Flash is deprecated on mobile devices now...so your
>   uploader won't work on iphone for one and flash has been taken off of
>   Android Market place last I checked.

Along with many others.

However it does actually upload to your server through PHP.

You will just need to as @NickRippe said set `upload_max_filesize` and you will also need to set `max_post_size` (though I am sure I read something about that too if I can find the link).

The other fields that most people talk about are not needed. I did some real digging when I came to do this and I found out from PHP mailing list and bug reports that 90% of the stuff people say isn't true.

Here are some that peple say you should set but you don't really need to:

`max_execution_time`

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16880, there are others like this where the community admit the execution has no effect until after upload.

`memory_limit`

[Relationship between php’s memory_limit, upload_max_filesize and post_max_filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106871/relationship-between-phps-memory-limit-upload-max-filesize-and-post-max-filesi) there is also the bug report on this somewhere but can't find it now.

`max_input_time`

[PHP file upload affected or not by max_input_time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387113/php-file-upload-affected-or-not-by-max-input-time)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the `upload_max_filesize`

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

This should ensure no one can upload files over 200MB