# How could I increase my maximum file upload size in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using the .htacces method to achive this

Here is what I am using so far

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

But each time I am getting error

```
Internal Server Error
```

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [increase max upload limit in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751779/increase-max-upload-limit-in-wordpress)

Comment: Please notice: Time limits do NOT affect the upload: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387113/php-file-upload-affected-or-not-by-max-input-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok great, I just got it!!

Adding the followwing code in "wp-admin" folder does the trick

```
memory_limit = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to change its settings through php.ini file. Find/change following options:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

Answer (score 1):

Save this code in any php file and update it in the plugins directory and activate that plugin:

```
ini_set('upload_max_size','256M');
ini_set('post_max_size','256M');
ini_set('max_Execution_time','600');
```

Comment: thanks buddy for helping me, I just figured it out. It needs to be added in the "wp-admin" folder

Answer (score 0):

You can put these lines before or after any other script in you .htaccess file. Save it and upload. That's it! Hope this helps!

```
#Change upload limits

php_value memory_limit 34M
php_value post_max_size 33M
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value max_execution_time 600

#Change upload limits end
```

Comment: Nah, that is not working, throwing the internal server error

The below is my .htaccess code



# BEGIN WordPress
php_value memory_limit 34M
php_value post_max_size 33M
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value max_execution_time 600
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file insert the following lines of code into it if it is not there and increase upload_max_filesize according to your requirements:

```
memory_limit = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
```

Answer (score 0):

As a summary of the above:

I add the following code in the .htaccess file in the directory wp-admin:

```
php_value memory_limit 34M
php_value post_max_size 33M
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value max_execution_time 600
```

and it worked.