# Best methods for simulating/testing performance under slow connections?

Tags: asp.net, testing

I am looking for a 'standard' tool for testing application performance under slower internet connections.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection) thread, but it appears the program is not designed for Windows 7. I am developing under Win 7 x64.

What other tools are out there which are worth taking a look at?

EDIT: I am exploring the usage of Sloppy right now. It seems like it will work best for my purposes. http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are software options for this, but at work we connect to our lan through a switch with rate limiting capability whenever we need this functionality.  Some of these hardware switches are pretty cheap, with the added bonus that there is no need to install any software on the computer (plus it works for any OS).

Comment: Not entirely sure I consider 'using hardware' an added bonus to not having to install software. I would rather have another program on my computer than another piece of equipment in my office space, but I think that's just because we're in a small enough place to have to deal with the hardware. Agreed on the works for any OS, though. +1'ed, but still looking for better answers.

Comment: @SeanAnderson if you are developing a web based app and just want to limit bandwidth to the browser, there are a couple of FireFox extensions that will do the job.  I can't vouch for them though--the one we used to use is no longer available.  One of my coworkers says he uses the "netbalancer" software on Win7x64, but again I can't vouch for it personally.  Hopefully someone else will chime-in with something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

The industry defacto tools for modeling impairment of slowed network connections come from Shunra (http://www.shunra.com).   You can also use an open source solution like WANem (http://wanem.sourceforge.net) to represent less complex impairment situations.