# Create lag on demand

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

This is kind of a strange question, but I need to create artificial lag to test how my game runs during lag spikes... I don't have the slightest clue of how to do it...
I'd like to be able to turn the lag on/off if that's possible.

Comment: other inputs on simulating a slow network: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to slow your code down, you could introduce blocking using the NSThread class method `sleepForTimeInterval:`.

To simulate a slow network connection, [Craig Hockenberry](https://twitter.com/#!/chockenberry) wrote [this blog post](http://furbo.org/2009/03/24/slow-ride-make-it-easy/) a while back.