# Sporadic un-evaluated values when using knockout-deferred-updates

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs 2.0 & the knockout-deferred-updates plugin. I am encountering sporadic null object reference errors in my bindings, due, presumably, to the timing of evaluating the various callbacks. I am looking for some guidance on how to determine whether (or which) items to set `deferredUpdates = false`.

As an alternative, I have put in test code in the binding to check if the value obtained from the `valueAccessor()` call is null; if so, I do not evaluate the binding function. While this might work for `update` handlers, it doesn't seem like a good idea for `init` ones.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Gene

Comment: I'm having the same issues too. I tried putting .extend({ throttle: 500 }); to see if that solves your issues.. it did with me but I'm not happy with that.. I'm still trying to figure out that deferred updates plugin.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but recently I ran into these problems much more frequently when running on a slower network. My sense is that because the timing of responses from the server changed, the various event handlers in knockoutjs and the deferred updates plugin where firing in a different sequence than when I am at home, and that revealed some problems. This is just a guess, however.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously any problem that happens sporadically is difficult to solve, but if it does appear to be caused by slower network response, you can try [simulating a slow connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection) to be able to reproduce the problem more consistently. That should let you debug it better (or at least narrow down the problem).

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a good tack to take. Know of any such tools that will work with 64bit Win7? None of the links in the post you site refer to this OS (maybe because it wasn't released yet a the time the answers were written!)

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) might work for you. It was mentioned in [one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3330197/1287183).

Comment: Also, if you aren't using the latest version of the deferred updates plugin, please try it to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry -- been away at a conference -- will get back to this next week!

Comment: Great. I also suggest trying the latest version of Knockout, 2.1, that was released recently.

Comment: Yes, I did upgradate to that, and it did fix some other problems I was seeing. I will need to test this to see if the sporadic problems went away as well.