# Intentionally slow down localhost web server

Tags: iphone, macos, localhost

I am working on an iphone app and for testing i am using localhost server for sending/receiving requests/responses.

But the speed seems to very fast from actual download and upload on 3G or other mobile data network.

I want to test my app with slower internet connection.

Is there any way I can slower down my macbook's apache server?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a 'slug' into the server code that processes your request, e.g. the PHP module you're calling. A simple slug would be a for loop that will tie up the server program before it responds. Or something that copies large files.

You'll need to experiment until you get the right sort of delay.