# Simulate no network with Visual studio 2012 tablet emulator

Tags: c#, networking, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am currently writing a WinRT application that has some network access to retrieve various details, I need to be able to simulate conditions when there is no network, or a very slow network to ensure that the app works as it should under these conditions.

How do I get the tablet emulator that is part of Visual Studio 2012 to simulate these conditions?

Cheers,
Rupert

Answer (score 2):

To simulate "no network" you have to disable the networking on the host computer.  It seems that the simulator shares the network with the host.

In regards to a slow network connection, you likely have to do this on the host again.  See this post: [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)