# network packet loss delay bandwidth simulation

Tags: networking, udp, delay, simulation, packet-loss

So I have come across many network simulators and most of them are either on permanently (as in you have to close it to turn it off), or have a stop and start button. now, I have been looking for a network simulator than can simulate packet loss, delay, bandwidth speeds of choice for windows that can also be cycled on or off by a set time. I found one such program called FnLag, but the problem is (for me at least) is that it is not free.

basically the shorter version of my question is does anyone know of a network simulator for windows or linux that is free that can simulate packet loss, delay, bandwidth control, seperate downstream and upstream rules, tcp and udp selection that can be cycled on and off or burst/pulse feature? i can elaborate further if necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)

Answer (score 3):

There is a very good **open source** solution for network simulations called - **WANEM**

WANem is a wide area network emulator. It supports various features such a bandwidth limitation, latency, packet loss, network disconnection among other wide area network characteristics.

Here is the url: [http://wanem.sourceforge.net](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/)

[image]