# How to slow down webpage loading time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, load

What can I do to slow down the page loading time. Is there any code that I can use in JavaScript, PHP, HTML or CSS to slow down page loading time without displaying anything else. This is for a function I want to test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is your site you are using PHP you can put a sleep(5) to delay the page loading for 5 seconds.

If it is not, a possible option is to use a proxy server

Comment: +1 for suggesting a proxy server. This other StackOverflow question might be good reading: [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)

Answer (score 3):

Using internet explorer you can use aptimize latency simluator - his lets you simulate different connection speeds.