# Make php webpage load slow, technique

Tags: php, jquery

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315636/how-to-slow-down-webpage-loading-time).

I want to write a function which will make my page load slow(for perticular time), and I want to display **browser's** loading icon until the page loads completely,
delay didn't worked as it only works with animation effects

Comment: http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/

Comment: I don't really see why anyone would want to do this, but you could try using the answer provided by Harsh over at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25219740](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25219740)

Comment: Thanks that was great, however  browser loading icon is stopped when page, loaded

Comment: unless you hate your users, **why** would you ever deliberately want to make your page *slow*?

Comment: for some user, admin want to make the website slower and want users to purchase pro package to reduce loading time, so he will get more profit

Comment: I end up with implementing @KevinF. answer into site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your loading icon within a div with id `loader` with CSS as following.

```
#loader {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

And your jQuery as:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loader").hide();
});
```

Comment: it should be browser loading Icon, which we see when site is loading

Comment: not the actual solution, but end up implementing same solution