# It is possible to make localhost network respond slower?

Tags: php, android, android-volley, mamp

Basically i'm debugging for slow network. Which I want is to handle those issues which experience by user who currently having slow connection such as timeout, retry connection etc. That seem impossible if I using MAMP as the server to debug which it is obviously extremely fast.

So here is the question :

1. It's possible to modify the respond speed of the MAMP?
2. It's okay to implement like `sleep()` functionality in server side code to delay the device receiving the data?
3. If you feel okay with the second question. Here come the third question, will this giving me a good experience ?

I know this is surely possible just didn't where to start.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use a proxy, like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) (commercial), or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (free). You will be able to throttle the connection.

Comment: Also maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection

Comment: Okay I will take look. Thank.