# How to simulate poor networks for *stress test* & Which aspects to simulate?

Tags: java, linux, networking

I am doing stress tests to simulate mobile phone users visiting our app (actually, connecting through WebSocket). I want to simulate poor network conditions, since you know, mobile phones often suffer from bad networks.

**Question 1:** We are doing stress test with 100,000 clients, so we need a efficient method to simulate poor networks. (Most software I have seen only simulate one mobile device)

**Question 2**: Which aspects should I simulate? For instance, I know network latency and packet loss. But are these all? 
Thanks very much for any suggestions!

Comment: For question 1 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection

Comment: @pifor Thanks so much!