# Is there a way to emulate loss link using batch scripting?

Tags: c++, batch-file, networking, visual-c++

I have point-to-point udp communication representing an uplink/downlink between two systems running on separate computers. The objective is to emulate intermittent comms loss between the two, as disconnecting the Ethernet switch isn't an elegant solution especially for the intermittent behavior.

Would it be possible to intercept the packet on a given port and drop packets. The objective isn't to deactivate the network interface, as that will cause specific failures in the uplink system. The objective rather to maintain the link but a lossy link nonetheless (intermittent loss of packets) ?

Comment: Whoever close voted as seeking library, this question is not doing that. An answer may (and probably will) use a library, but the question itself is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)

Comment: I also found https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/